# Why my .autocomplete isn't working?

Tags: jquery, json, cakephp, autocomplete

I'm using this code to get a json with districts for an autocomplete input.
The json is working, i can see it with firebug, but the autocomplete isnt firing.

I just want to use the returned json as source for autocomplete.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#AdCityId').change(function() {
        var city = $('#AdCityId').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://mydomain.com/classi/ads/getDistrictsByCity",
            type: "GET",
            data: {city: city},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
                $( "#AdDistrict" ).autocomplete({
                  source: result
                });
            }
        });
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consult the [Jquery UI docs](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote). It's a load easier to do something like this.

```
$( "#AdCityId" ).autocomplete({
      source: "http://mydomain.com/classi/ads/getDistrictsByCity?city="+$('#AdCityId').val(),
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        //do selecting stuff here if any
      }
    });
```

Comment: Since AdCityID is ajax filled $('#AdCityId').val() is blank :(